# Hibernate sending null values to database table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, dropwizard

I am using Dropwizard java example implemented [HERE](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/tree/master/examples/server/java)

I only made one change replacing database with SQL server.it is working well by creating table with columns in sql server too.

Post request to localhost:3000/auth/signup gets correct data.

**AuthController.java:**

```
 @Path("signup")
 @UnitOfWork
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Response signup(@Valid final User user, @Context final HttpServletRequest request)
  throws JOSEException {
  System.out.print(user);
  user.setPASSWORD(PasswordService.hashPassword(user.getPASSWORD()));
  final User savedUser = dao.save(user);
  final Token token = AuthUtils.createToken(request.getRemoteHost(), savedUser.getUSER_ID());
 return Response.status(Status.CREATED).entity(token).build();
 }
```

Here post data is correct also checked in userdao.

**UserDAO.java:**

```
  public User save(User user) {
    System.out.print(user);
    return persist(user);
 }
```

Correct data here too.

**User.java:**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "TBLLOGINUSER")
    @NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM User u"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByEmail", query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.USER_NAME = :email")
   })
  public class User {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long USER_ID;

   @Email
   @Column(name = "USER_NAME")
   private String USER_NAME;

   @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
   private String PASSWORD;

   @Column(name = "LAST_LOGIN")
   private String LAST_LOGIN;

   @Column(name = "STATUS")
   private String STATUS;


   public Long getUSER_ID() {
    return USER_ID;
    }
   public String getUSER_NAME() {
    return USER_NAME;
   }
   public String getSTATUS() {
    return STATUS;
    }

    public String getLAST_LOGIN() {
    return LAST_LOGIN;
    }
    @JsonIgnore
    public String getPASSWORD() {
    return PASSWORD;
   } 

     public void setUSER_NAME(final String email) {
     this.USER_NAME = email;
    }
    public void setPASSWORD(final String password) {
    this.PASSWORD = password;
   }

    public void setLAST_LOGIN(final String name) {
    this.LAST_LOGIN = name;
   }
   public void setSTATUS(final String name) {
    this.STATUS = name;
     }
    public void setUSER_ID(final Long name) {
   this.USER_ID = name;
   } 
   @JsonIgnore
    public int getSignInMethodCount() throws IllegalArgumentException,IllegalAccessException,
  NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException {
   int count = 0;

    if (this.getPASSWORD() != null) {
  count++;
   } return count;
   }

    }
```

but logging tells something like this.

```
   DEBUG [2016-07-08 09:29:31,472] org.hibernate.SQL: /* insert   com.example.helloworld.core.User */ insert into TBLLOGINUSER (LAST_LOGIN,   PASSWORD, STATUS, USER_NAME)  values(?, ?, ?, ?)
   WARN  [2016-07-08 09:29:31,480] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 22001
   ERROR [2016-07-08 09:29:31,480] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: Data truncation
   WARN  [2016-07-08 09:29:31,480] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: SQL Error: 8152, SQLState: 22001
   ERROR [2016-07-08 09:29:31,480] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: String or binary data would be truncated.
   ERROR [2016-07-08 09:29:31,486] org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.example.helloworld.core.User entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
  INFO  [2016-07-08 09:29:31,488] org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener: Session  Metrics {
70528 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
1983808 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
4599920 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
3196256 nanoseconds spent executing 1 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
   }
   WARN  [2016-07-08 09:29:31,507] org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler:! org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in com.example.helloworld.core.User entry (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)
```

Any idea why null values are sent to db????

Comment: you must add mapping of USER_ID with db column, @Column(name = "USER_ID")

Comment: primary keys in other tables are also added as @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long USER_ID; and working fine.anyhoo let me check it.

Comment: no it will show conflict in upper declaration as identity.

Comment: I think the problem is where your parameter @Valid final User user come from. Its variable value user_id was set to null by the caller and when the user_id is set ( event to null ) hibernate will not able to generate the auto identity for you. In this case your User parameter come from Json so you can add @ JsonIgnore to user_id variable to avoid this id is setup by Json parser.

Comment: i am sending this data through postman:{
 
"user_NAME":"abc@gmail",
"password":"abc",
"status":"1"
}

Comment: do i need to add id parameter here?

Comment: As you can see in the generated sql, the user_id is not sent at all. This might be because of the way the object is handled by Jackson when deserialized. You can try to add @JsonIgnore on the user_id, maybe then hibernate will handle it correctly.